# Moving axios calls out of React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

Is this an anti-pattern in React if I do this? How can I improve?

I have an EventItem Component and another helper file - EventHelper.js which handles all the axios calls for the said component. The functions declared in this helper file receives states and setStates from the EventItem component. The functions in this helper file make the HTTP calls and sets the state in EventItem component. Something like this:

EventItem.js (Component):

```
import {getPostComments} from "../Services/EventHelpers";

function EventItem(props) {
  const [eventComments, setEventComments] = useState([]);
  const [loadingComments, setLoadingComments] = useState(false);

  const getPostCommentsHandler = async (eventId) => {
    await getPostComments(
      eventId,
      setLoadingComments,
      eventComments,
      setEventComments
    );
  };
}
```

EventHelper.js:

```
export const getPostComments = async (
  eventId,
  setLoadingComments,
  eventComments,
  setEventComments
) => {
  try {
    setLoadingComments(true);
    const res = await axios.get(`/events/${eventId}/comments`);
    setLoadingComments(false);
    setEventComments(...[...eventComments, res.data.comments]);
  } catch (e) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of writing this code is a valid way. For these kind of states and functions React recommends creating [custom hooks](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks).

The following code allows you to move all your state needed for getting the post comments to a separate hook. This will result in a cleaner component and you can reuse this hook in a different component.

```js
export function usePostComments() {
  const [eventComments, setEventComments] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const getPostComments = async (eventId) => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const res = await axios.get(`/events/${eventId}/comments`);

      setEventComments((prevComments) => {
        return [...prevComments, res.data.comments];
        // or this below, not sure if you're comments data is a array
        // return [...prevComments, ...res.data.comments];
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return {
    isLoading,
    eventComments,
    getPostComments,
  };
}
```

In the `EventItem` you could use it something like this, obviously very abstract but you'll get the idea.

```js
import { usePostComments } from "../hooks";

function EventItem(props) {
  const { isLoading, eventComments, getPostComments } = usePostComments();

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => getPostComments("some-id")}>Get posts</button>
      {isLoading ? (
        <p>Sorry still loading</p>
      ) : (
        <div>
          {eventComments.map((comment) => {
            <p>{comment.stuff}</p>;
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I really liked your approach! Definitely a cleaner way of writing code. Although I do have a question. We are exporting getPostComments() from usePostComments(). When we are calling the getPostComments() in the handler, I quite don't understand how eventComments is being updated. I dont know how to frame this properly. I mean, we're just setting state in getPostComments() but aren't returning anything. Only usePostComments() is returning an object and that too once! Can you please help me understand this better?

Comment: So when you call `getPostComments` with a `eventId` in your `EventItem` the `eventComments` state is being updated and the will return the new state, the same for the `isLoading` state. You can see the custom hook as the default ReactJS counter example, if you click the increment button the state is being changed, which will return the component's elements with the new updated counter value. Only in our case with the custom hook it will return the updated state with the `eventComments` and `isLoading`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
// api.js

import axios from 'axios'

const api = {
  comments: async (eventId) => {
    const res = await axios.get(`/events/${eventId}/comments`);
    return res
  }
}
export default api
```

Whereby

```
// EventItem.js
import {getPostComments} from "../Services/EventHelpers";

function EventItem(props) {
  const [eventComments, setEventComments] = useState([]);
  const [loadingComments, setLoadingComments] = useState(false);

  const getPostCommentsHandler = async (eventId) => {
    await getPostComments(
      eventId,
      setLoadingComments,
      eventComments,
      setEventComments
    );
  };
}
```

Such that the EventHelper.js is thus:

```
// EventHelper.js
import api from './api'

export const getPostComments = async (
  eventId,
  setLoadingComments,
  eventComments,
  setEventComments
) => {
  try {
    setLoadingComments(true);
    const comments = await api.comments(eventId)
    setLoadingComments(false);
    setEventComments(...[...eventComments, comments]);
  } catch (e) {}
};
```

Explaination:

For the api.js - you may want to abstract the api to be used in various components/hooks. the idea is that when anyone can use the api (where there is a common interface).